# Replace regex \\+n from string in swift

Tags: swift, regex

i want to remove every string starts with one or more `\` and follow with `n`.
For example:
input: `{\n\n abc \\nb\\\ncc}`
expect output: `{ abc bcc}`
In javascript it works with regex `/\\+n/g`
But it doesn't work in swift:

```
str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\+n", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: It looks like you want to remove both newlines and ``\`` + `n` char combinations. Try `#"\\+n|\\*\n"` to remove all `n`s that contain one or more backslashes in front, and all newlines with any amount of  backslashes in front.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it works like charm, why do we need `#` at the beginning and ending? Please give me some detail.

Comment: I think you need to escape \ as well, so it needs to be "double" escaped (first in string in swift and sceondly in regex), so it look like `"\\\\+n"`

Comment: Hey, this syntax is only available from Swift 5.1, is there any other way for lower version? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all `n`s that contain one or more backslashes in front, and all newlines with any amount of  backslashes in front, you can use

```
#"\\+n|\\*\n"#
```

Note the `#` before and after the double quotes mean that the literal is a raw string literal where backslashes are treated as literal backslashes and do not form string escape sequences, like `\n`, `\t`, `\r`, etc.

Here, the pattern means

- `\\+n` - one or more backslashes followed with `n`
- `|` - or
- `\\*\n` - zero or more backslashes followed with a newline.

Note that here, `\n` is a regex escape matching a newline, it is not an LF, `\x0A` character.